# Very slow loading time to render 7k of records in a Tabulator grid

Tags: javascript, php, magento2, tabulator

I need some help with this library, it is not working properly or I am not doing it right. I am using PHP `foreach` to call and put the JSON/data together then JS to take the data and render it, any clue what I could be doing wrong?

```
<script>
 var tabledata = [
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <?php $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $imageDisplayArea); ?>
        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
        {picture:"<?php echo $productImage->getImageUrl() ?>", material:"<a href=\"<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>\"><?php echo $_product->getName() ?></a>", description:"<?php echo htmlspecialchars(trim($_product->getProhyddescription())) ?>", productCategory:"<?php echo $_product->getProdcat() ?>", shortName:"<?php echo $_product->getShortname() ?>", orderCode:"<?php echo trim($_product->getOrdercode()) ?>", literature:"<?php echo $_product->getIncluded() ?>", notes:"<?php echo $_product->getNotes() ?>", qtyDBN:"<?php echo $_product->getQtydbn() ?>", qtyWHS:"<?php echo $_product->getQtywhs() ?>", price:"<?php echo $_product->getPrice() ?>", mda:"<?php echo $_product->getMda() ?>", order:"<form data-role=\"tocart-form\" data-product-sku=\"<?=$block->escapeHtml($_product->getSku()) ?>\" action=\"<?=/* @NoEscape */ $postParams['action'] ?>\" method=\"post\"> <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"product\" value=\"<?=/* @escapeNotVerified */ $postParams['data']['product'] ?>\"/> <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"<?=/* @escapeNotVerified */ Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>\" value=\"<?=/* @escapeNotVerified */ $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED] ?>\"/> <?= addslashes($block->getBlockHtml('formkey')) ?> <button type=\"submit\" title=\"<?=$block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?>\" class=\"action tocart primary\"> <span> <?=/* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?> </span></button> </form>", stdTime:"<?php echo $_product->getStdleadtime() ?>" },
    <?php endforeach; ?>
 ];
 
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
     var table = new Tabulator("#products", {
        height:600, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
        data: tabledata, //assign data to table
        layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
        pagination:"local",
        paginationSize:300,
        headerSort:true,
        virtualDomBuffer: 500,
        cellHozAlign:"center",
        columnCalcs:"both",
        paginationSizeSelector:[300, 500, 600, 700, 800, 1000],
            columns:[ //Define Table Columns
            {title:"Picture", field:"picture", width:100, responsive: 0, formatter:"image"},
            {title:"Material", field:"material", formatter:"html", headerFilter:true},
            {title:"Description", field:"description", headerFilter:true},
            {title:"Product Category", field:"productCategory", headerFilter:true},
            //{title:"Short Name", field:"shortName", headerFilter:true},
            {title:"Order Code", field:"orderCode", headerFilter:true},
            {title:"Literature", field:"literature", headerFilter:true, headerTooltip:"Included in Latest Catalog Literature? (Promote On New Applications)"},
            {title:"Notes", field:"notes", headerFilter:true},
            {title:"Qty DBN", field:"qtyDBN", sorter:"number", headerFilter:true},
            {title:"Qty WHS", field:"qtyWHS", sorter:"number", headerFilter:true},
            {title:"Price", field:"price", formatter:"money", formatterParams:{
                symbol:"R",
            }},
            {title:"MDA", field:"mda"},
            {title:"Order", field:"order", formatter:"html"},
            {title:"STD L/Time", field:"stdTime", headerFilter:true},
        ]
     });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: reduce `virtualDomBuffer: 500,` should be less than 300. And 300 is too much for pagination

Comment: @xdeepakv I tried that but did not notice any difference, still, PHP seems to be the core issue here.

Comment: What about loading the records incrementally using an AJAX request, instead of all at once? It might be a good idea to use a Generator in PHP to reduce the overall memory footprint.

Comment: @Julianv.dBerkmortel Could you point me to some sort of a sample/example/reference?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have your page size set so high, if you are paginating your data then you shouldn't have a scroll bar in your table, you either want to set the table height and let tabulator fill the space with the number of rows that fit, or set the page size and let tabulator determine the height

Paginating data with 300 rows a page rather defeats the point of paginating, which is what is slowing things down

Comment: Although, I feel the PHP iteration is the core problem would not you agree with me? as you can see I am pulling a lot of data from the DB "Magento DB"; what do you recommend in this regard?